# Pagenumbering in \tableofcontents \listoffigures and \listoftables with fancyhdr not working

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am writing my Bachelorthesis in sharelatex.com and compiling with XeLaTeX.
In the following code I want the **\tableofcontents \listoffigures** and **\listoftables** to have the pagenumbering in Roman lettering at the top right. However it does not work. The rest of the pages has it. I want it in the style of **\fancyhdr**.
Is there a way to force this? or did I miss anything?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=20mm,left=35mm,right=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % für Grafiken
%\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption} %Überschriften für Bilder
\captionsetup{font={small,it}}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float} %Position erzwingen
\usepackage{array} %feste Spaltenbreite einstellbar
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{acronym}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \Huge
    Titlepage
\end{titlepage}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em} %keine Einrückung nach Absatz


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\pagenumbering{Roman}


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Affidavit}
\section*{Affidavit}
Affidavit
\clearpage   %\input{Affidavit}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\section*{List of Abbreviations}

\begin{acronym}[TCP]
\acro{TCP}{Transmission Control Protocol}
\end{acronym}

\clearpage


\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\clearpage

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\clearpage



\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Mainbody}
Text

\clearpage


% \pagenumbering{Roman}
% \fancyhf{}
% \rhead{\thepage}
% \setcounter{page}{6}
% \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}\clearpage
% \nocite{*}
% \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
% \bibliography{References}
% \clearpage

% \begin{appendix}
%  \input{Sections/Appendix}\clearpage
% \end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Commands like `\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents` use `\thispagestyle{plain}`.  You can either disable this feature (`\let\thispagestyle=\@gobble`) or redefine plain (see `\fancypagestyle{plain}` on pages 7-8).

Comment: Thank you very much, you made my day @JohnKormylo! I changed it and it worked. The answer is at the bottom and also in the link it is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}
```

to change the page style of the first page in ToC, LoF and LoT to `fancy`. (By default `tocloft` uses `plain` for these pages even if the class is `article`.)

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}%<- sets the page style on the first page of ToC, LoF and LoT

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}%<- add an ToC entry for LoF and LoT

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that I have used package `tocbibind` to get an entry of LoF and LoT in ToC.

Without package `tocbibind` you could use:

```
\cftafterloftitle{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}}
\cftafterlottitle{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}}
```

Comment: yes that works fine as well! And this step can be omitted, which I almost forgot (I am quite new to LaTeX): `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}`

Comment: Yes, do not add the ToC entries manuelly. The code in your MWE would result in wrong page numbers in ToC if LoF or LoT needs more than one page (your code uses the page number of the last LoF/LoT page). You could load package `tocbibind` or use `tocloft` commands (see my updated answer). BTW If the answer helps, then you can upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @John Kormylo I changed the "pagestyle settings" to:
and it worked immediately!

```
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\fancypagestyle{plain}  %%%%%%%VERY IMPORTANT%%%%%%%%%%
```